# Removing redundancies in sql query that contains subquery

Tags: sql, azure, subquery

Suppose we have a table with scheme

```
student(id (primary key), name, math_score, english_score)
```

I am trying to get student information (id and name) with highest rank (ordered by highest sum of math score and english score). There may be several student with tie, and we want all of them. The way I thought about doing this is to use subquery to get a table with sum of scores, then find ids, names that have highest sum.

```
SELECT s.id, s.name
FROM (SELECT s.id, s.name, s.math_score+s.english_score as sum
      FROM student s) s
WHERE s.sum = (SELECT max(s.sum)
               FROM (SELECT s.id, s.name, s.math_score+s.english_score as sum
                     FROM student s) s)
```

This works, but seems very redundant and not efficient.

I just started learning sql language, and I would appreciate some insight on this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WITH TIES

```
create table #student(
    id int primary key identity(1,1), 
    name varchar(50), 
    math_score decimal, 
    english_score decimal
)

insert into #student
values
('Tom', 90, 90),
('Dick', 70, 70),
('Harry', 80, 100)

select TOP(1) WITH TIES
    id, 
    name, 
    math_score, 
    english_score, 
    math_score + english_score as ScoreRank
from #student
order by
    math_score + english_score desc
```

Gives the answer:

```
id|name|math_score|english_score|ScoreRank
1|Tom|90|90|180
3|Harry|80|100|180
```

Comment: He wants the students with the top score including ties... it works, try the example yourself.

Comment: Thank you, this method fits my need best!

Answer (score 1):

This should accomplish it, you're adding in an unnecessary step.

```
select id, 
       name, 
       math_score+english_score as total_score
from student
where math_score+english_score=(select max(math_score+english_score)
                                from student)
```

Comment: Turns out, `in` doesnt work in this example, [but `=` does](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/967e1/2).+1

Answer (score -1):

```
        SELECT id, name, math_score+english_score as 'sum'
        FROM student
        Order by math_score+english_score DESC;
```

Comment: I didnt downvote you, but this offers no restriction of the top rank.  It shows the whole table.

Comment: The OP asked for "There may be several student with tie, and we want **all of them**"

Comment: I interpret that to mean all of the ties... not all of the records.

Comment: The original question is confusing "(ordered by highest sum of math score and english score)" then why would you only want to limit to the MAX(Score)?  that would only get the ones who have the max not the entire list

Comment: I agree, its not the best worded question.  I also take a clue from the sql that OP has tried to write.  They clearly want only the max values from that.